# Codeigniter active record help

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to add search functionality onto my website, the user can search for jobs using sector names, so for example they may want to search for

> IT, MEDIA, INTERNET, MARKETING

I want take this search term and return all the jobs the match that search term, however a job may have more than one sector, but I only want the job to be returned once.

Below is my current code, which does not work,

```
public function getJobsBySector($criteria)
{

        $criteria = explode("," $criteria);
        $this->db->select('job_id, job_title, salary, retrain, bonuses_available, bonus_description, job_summary, job_description,  company_name, company_summary, logo_small, logo_large, employers.employer_id')
        ->from('jobs')
        ->join('employers', 'employers.employer_id = jobs.employer_id', 'left')
    //  ->join('applications', 'applications.jobs_job_id = jobs.job_id', 'left')
        $i = 0;
        foreach($criteria as $cri) {
            $this->db->like('sector', $cri[$i])
            $i++;
        }

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Consider changing the question title so others might find it.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL SELECTs can have `DISTINCT` modifier, which will make it return any matching row only once.
Codeigniter has a special method to add `DISTINCT` to your query.

```
...
$this->db->select('job_id, job_title, salary, retrain, bonuses_available, bonus_description, job_summary, job_description,  company_name, company_summary, logo_small, logo_large, employers.employer_id')
->disctinct()
->from('jobs')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this is wrong foreach use:

```
foreach($criteria as $cri) {
  $this->db->like('sector', $cri[$i])
  $i++;
}
```

it should be:

```
foreach($criteria as $cri) {
  $this->db->like('sector', $cri)
}
```

BUT this will produce a query with ... LIKE something *AND* LIKE something_else, which is not what you want, so the right version should look like this:

```
foreach($criteria as $cri) {
  $this->db->or_like('sector', $cri)
}
```

And no worries about returning job just once as long as sector field is string, what seems to be the case here considering your code.